# bindFactory does not inject fields

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, hk2

I have this code to provide a custom injectable object:

```
    config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            delegatorFactory = ...; //custom factory to delegate to
            bindFactory(new Factory<Object>() {
                @Inject
                private Provider<ContainerRequestContext> req;

                @Override
                public void dispose(Object arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public Object provide() {
                    // req is needed but is null
                }
            }).to(delegatorFactory.getType()).in(RequestScoped.class);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, as the comment in provide() reveals, the `req` field is not injected when it is executed (I need the `ContainerRequestContext` at that location).
What am I missing to make it work like this, i.e. make the factory's fields injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind it with a class. Most of time, when you start instantiating stuff yourself, you lose the benefit of injection. So just use a class

```
bindFactory(YourFactoryClass.class)
```

---

#### UPDATE

To get the injector to manually inject the factory, you can use a `Feature`

```
public class YourFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public void configure(FeatureContext context) {
        final ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getLocator(context);

        locator.inject(anyObject);
  
        context.register(new YourAbstractBinder());
    }
}

config.register(new YourFeature());
```

Comment: Yes, I found out that using the factory type instead of the instance works, but I need to delegate the execution to a custom factory (from some other framework) that needs the ContainerRequestContext. Is there at least a way to get the injector to manually inject fields of the factory instance?